# Ingresar dato sin hacer foco en un input. Angular 10

Tags: html, typescript, angular10

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación para ingresar códigos 2D automáticamente con un scaner a medida que pasa un producto por una línea de producción. Lo que busco es que, este dato se ingrese, sin necesidad de estar focalizado en el input.
Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente.
componente.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-4"> <label for='panel'><b>Panel</b></label> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" name="panel" #panel="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="bar_code" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()" class="form-control" required autofocus>
    </div>
</div>
```

ya que el scaner ingresa un enter al final de la lectura, usé el evento (keyup.enter), y la verdad funciona perfecto, pero siempre debo tener el cursor dentro del input, y si alguien hace un click afuera perderé de trazar productos hasta que alguien cliquee otra vez allí.

luego dentro del componente.component.ts no tengo ningún problema, ya que uso una función que toma el evento:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Inspeccion } from 'src/app/models/inspeccion';
import { InspeccionesService } from 'src/app/services/inspecciones.service';
import { RouteOpService } from 'src/app/services/route-op.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClassGetter } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';




@Component({
 selector: 'app-inspecciones',
 templateUrl: './inspecciones.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./inspecciones.component.css']
 })
 export class InspeccionesComponent implements OnInit {
 public op: string;
 public bar_code: string;
 public inspeccionar:boolean; 
 public inspeccion: Inspeccion; 
 public datos: boolean=true;


 constructor(
  private _router: Router,
  private _routeOpService:     RouteOpService,
  private _inspeccionService: InspeccionesService
  ) { 

  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }



onEnter() {

this.inspeccion=new Inspeccion('',''); //modelo del arreglo que mando backend
this.inspeccion.op=this.op; 
this.inspeccion.barcode=this.bar_code; 
console.log(this.inspeccion);
this.bar_code=null;  //dejar en blanco el input
//servicio que va al backend
this._inspeccionService.addInspeccion(this.inspeccion).subscribe(
response=>{
    if(response.status="success"){
      console.log(response);
    }else{
      console.log("error al enviar datos"); 
    }
   },
   error=>{
     console.log(<any>error); 
   }

);
```

}

Desde aquí en adelante tengo claro lo que debo hacer.
Espero que se haya entendido.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes setear el valor del input cuando ya has leído el código 2D. No se como pasas el código leído al componente si puedes poner eso quizá pueda ayudarte más.

Comment: Lo paso con el [(ngModel)]="bar_code" , en el componente tengo definida la variable como: 
           public bar_code:numer;
luego en la función la llamo como  this.bar_code ;
Espero que ahí esté la respuesta a tu pregunta. Muchas gracias por ayudar.

Comment: No, si tal como dices que el código 2D se genera automáticamente te pregunto donde se genera ese código? Osea como seteas el valor del campo `bar_code` que esta linkado al `ngModel` en algun sitio harás `this.bar_code = codigo`? Eso es lo que pregunto

Comment: En realidad al código lo lee el scaner, un QR que viene pegado en el producto, y eso como si fuera un ingreso por teclado, lo mando por [(ngModel)], si te fijas en la función, onEnter hago un console.log  del dato y lo veo perfecto.

Comment: vale pero no lo estas seteando en el `onEnter` sino en otra parte de tu código que no has puesto. Pero bueno puedes mirar de escuhar el `(change)` en el input y asi mirar si tiene valor pues enviarlo al server.

Comment: hawks, ahora entendí tu planteo, por eso edité la consulta y sumé mas código al .ts Espero que eso ayude, pero me parece que el tema está en decirle al html que siempre esté atento a la entrada por teclado, aún cuando el cursor no esté sobre el campo input.

Comment: puedes mirarte los eventos `ngModelChange`, `input` quizá te sirvan. Más no puedo decirte.

Comment: Hay lectores de codigo QR que estan atentos a esa accion. Prueba con https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner. Si usas un lector como tal, entonces funciona como el teclado. Debes de llamar una funcion que ponga el focus en el input. Se puede lograr incluso con el movimiento del mouse.

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias por los comentarios. Estaré investigando a partir de sus recomendaciones. Saludos.